# How to get Xml tags from log file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a log file sample in which i have a error message plus xml tags eg

```
   error message
   xmltag
   error message
   xml tag
```

problem is i only want to get xml tag but i am getting error "Data at the root level is invalid."

c# code is

```
       XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg.log");
    var nodes = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message");
    var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes )
    {
        if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["Receiver"] != null && node.Attributes["Receiver"].Value == "+921215648545")
        {
            resultNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
```

xml file is

```
      some value
      some value
      <Message type="email">
         <Details locale="en">
          <Part type="plain" id="email/plain/User.ResetPassword.email"/>
          </Details>
        <Subject>New Password</Subject>
        <Sender>BB.Ops@example.com</Sender>
               <Context>
       <Parameter name="pswr" value="00"/>

        <Receiver>a.k@example.com</Receiver>
```

```
  some value
  some value
     <Message type="email">
      <Details locale="en">
         <Part type="plain" id="email/plain/User.ResetPassword.email"/>
      </Details>
        <Subject>New Password</Subject>
         <Sender>BB.Ops@example.com</Sender>
       <Context>
            <Parameter name="pswr" value="00"/>
        </Context>
               <Receiver>a.k@example.com</Receiver>
      </Message>
```

Comment: You should show us how are you retrieving this xml code and how you're using it. I guess that also a real log message would be helpful.

Comment: I agree, actually showing us the XML that you're parsing would be vital. Are you trying to parse the entire log file as XML? That might be the cause but without seeing the real content it will be very hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: some lines consist of message and some are tags

Comment: Are you trying to parse that entire log file as XML? Or are you reading the XML text and then trying to parse it?

Comment: XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg.log");
        var nodes = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message");
        var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes )
        {
            if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["Receiver"] != null && node.Attributes["Receiver"].Value == "+921215648545")
            {
                resultNodes.Add(node);
            }
        }

Comment: i am reading a file through xml document and finding tag values

Comment: You can't simply load the log file as XML because it's not XML - it's a text file that contains within it some XML.

Comment: view edited post can u suggest me how i overcome my problem

Comment: can i parse a log file into xml file which contains only xml tags?

Comment: In your question, the first section of XML is invalid - there's no closing `Context` or `Message` tag.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the file is not xml.  You need to read each line and determine if it's part of the xml or part of the message.  As the xml isn't on a single line and the messages can be any length, this may be a bit hit-and-miss.

One possible solution, which works *only for the example you've provided*, would be something like:

```
var filename = "...";
var xmlText = new StringBuilder();
bool isXml = false;
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    if (line.Trim().StartsWith("<Message"))
        isXml = true;

    if (isXml)
    {
        xmlText.Append(line);
        if (line.Trim().EndsWith("</Message>"))
        {
            //var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText.ToString());
            var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(xmlText.ToString());

            //process xml here

            xmlText.Clear();
            isXml = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can change the output format of the log file, I'd recommend that to make parsing so much easier, eg add a line before and after the xml with just the text [XML] then you can look for that token.

*Edit*: Update to use XmLDocument rather than XDocument.

Comment: how can i write this xdoc into another xml file so that i can easily read data from it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to load the entire log file as XML:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg.log");
```

That's not going to work, because the log file isn't an XML file - it's a text file that just happens to contain some XML.

You'll need to parse the log file and extract the XML in order to load it with `XmlDocument` - there are many ways of parsing text files, without more knowledge of your problem domain I won't go into those details here.

Comment: thank u but can u suggest please i have searched a lot on internet how to convert a log file into xml file but i couldn't find

Comment: That's because there are many different ways of doing it - I don't know the format of your log files so suggesting anything here would simply be wild speculation.